# Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.9hCo4Y (%build)

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, offline, rhel6, network-driver

Currently working with a RHEL 6 offline system.

I am using a RHEL6 repo server to compile a new IGB driver (Intel® Network Adapter Driver for 82575/6, 82580, I350, and I210/211-based Gigabit Network Connections for Linux*) with a RHEL6 kernel update. It will be included in a RHEL6 patch update for an offline system. The IGB driver version I am using is igb-5.13.7 and the kernel update I am using for this patch is 2.6.32-754.48.1.el6 (x86_64).

When I use the command "rpmbuild -tb igb-5.13.7.tar.gz", the compilation errors out and I receive the following message: "Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.9hCo4Y (%build)".

The last IGB network driver I compiled successfully was igb-5.10.2. Since then, I installed the most recent RHEL6 kernel update to the repo server, removed the old repodata, created new repodata, ran yum update, and restarted the repo started. I have done nothing out of the ordinary for my patch update and I have no idea why I am receiving the above error.

I read on another Stack Overflow question that if you look in the network driver's spec file (in this case igb.spec), you can find the error on line 28. For me, line 28 was "LANG=C" so I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Any advice on how to fix this issue or about what files I should look into?

---

I've tried using an older version of the IGB driver (igb-5.11.4) in case the new driver file was bad. I've tried redownloading the IGB driver I was using (igb-5.13.7) in case the file I had was corrupted.

I've tried checking the SPEC file which was recommended in another Stack Overflow to find the issue on line 28.

I've tried deleting all of the patch files and network driver from the repo server to start the whole process over from scratch. Same issue arises every time.

I've tried a solution that involves rebuilding an RPM from the Source RPM, installing the RPM spec, and rebuilding the package. However, I can't find the source RPM for the latest IGB driver. Willing to continue down this path if someone knows where to find the igb-5.13.7 source rpm or how to obtain it.